# get clientState data from inside ApolloClient's request for use in operation.setContext react apollo graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

React - Apollo - GraphQl
hi everybody 
the code is :

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://someurl.com/graphqlserverendpoint/",
  fetchOptions:{
    credentials : "include" 
  },
  request : operation => { 
    // i want to access needed data from here
  const neededDataFromClientState = "QueryDataFromHere!!!"
  const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken') || "" ; 
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        Authorization : `JWT ${token}` 
      }
    })

  },
  clientState : {  
    defaults : { 
      isLoggedIn : !!localStorage.getItem('authToken') ,  
      neededData : "the data I want get"

    }
  }
});
```

i want to access data that named neededData from request Operation

Any body want to help me ? 
Thanks..

Comment: strange ApolloClient usage ... source/reasons?

Comment: do you want release a new course for teach apollo client in order to mitigate strange ApolloClient usage?

Comment: i just try implement auth system with jwt-token to my django backend. i'm newbie at react and it is hard to learn sometimes if you familiar another language. maybe i must began from js for it :)  i try to store jwt token clients cache and append header in all request. i dont want to store token browser storage. Maybe anyone have some solution for this station. Or maybe someone give an advice for better security when work with jwt token ? i searched but not find any tutorial. I used Django - graphql , django-graphql-jwt - react

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide imports - your `ApolloClient` is from `apollo-boost` project and this is why it's config options are different than standard imported from `apollo-client`.

### Outdated

> The Apollo Boost project is now retired, because Apollo Client 3.0 provides a similarly straightforward setup. We recommend removing all `apollo-boost` dependencies and modifying your `ApolloClient` constructor as needed.

Apollo boost **was** a 'easy starter' project meant to hide some config complexity ([a few lines more] cache and links config).

### Solution

Use normal, widely known auth methods described in [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/) and many tutorials like [this](https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/5-authentication/)

`localStorage` is used for keep user logged on page/browser refresh.

Other data can be passed between [links](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/overview/) by context - data can be stored completely externally like `token` in [this example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/context/#caching-lookups). Other (following in chain, order matters) link[-s] can read data from context using `operation.getContext().token` instead from localStorage.

Comment: thank you for enlightening me. I will try this solution. thanks thanks..